# Verify security header details of SOAP envelopes by a SOAP service using SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, usernametoken

Using SOAP UI, I am trying to build a SOAP service that supports web service securities. I used the Sample SOAP Project Core, to run the service from SOAP UI, and added `UsernameToken` security headers to the request.
The SOAP request looks like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sam="http://www.soapui.org/sample/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>your_username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>your_password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sam:login>
         <username>Login9</username>
         <password>Login1123</password>
      </sam:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Even though the headers are set in the request, I could not extract the token information and verify it from the SOAP service and generate the response based on the verification. Is there any way I can extract the security headers from SOAP envelope and verify it in SOAP service?